# When do you need to apply permissions to a synonym

Tags: sql-server, permissions, synonym

I see from [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) that you can apply permissions to a T-SQL synonym, but in playing around with synonyms I'm not clear when you would need to do that if you have already GRANTed permissions to the base object.

eg. If I have a synonym in database A that points to a table FRED in database B, then it appears that as long as user Joe is granted SELECT on [Fred].[B] then Joe can do SELECT * FROM [Fred].[B].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using Synonyms (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190626.aspx)

> The following permission statements
>   are associated only with the synonym
>   and not the base object: (then mentions GRANT, REVOKE; DENY)

After that, [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) applies.

> When an object is accessed through a
>   chain, SQL Server first compares the
>   owner of the object to the owner of
>   the calling object. This is the
>   previous link in the chain. If both
>   objects have the same owner,
>   permissions on the referenced object
>   are not evaluated.

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.FooBar FOR dbo.MyBaseProc
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.FooBar TO MyUser
GO
REVOKE EXECUTE ON dbo.MyBaseProc TO MyUser
GO
EXEC AS USER = 'MyUser'
GO
PRINT '1'
EXEC dbo.MyBaseProc --fail
GO
PRINT '2'
EXEC dbo.bob    --pass
GO
REVERT
GO


DENY EXECUTE ON dbo.MyBaseProc TO MyUser
GO
PRINT '3'
EXEC AS USER = 'MyUser'
GO
EXEC dbo.bob    --pass, 'coz DENY aint checked...
GO
REVERT
GO
```

Edit: I hope I've answered your question...

Comment: who is `bob`? :). I think it should be `dbo.FooBar` instead of all `dbo.bob`s

Comment: I don't understand how the synonym DML and DDL permissions differ, but in my case I had to allow CRUD permissions on the synonym object and also CRUD permissions on the base / underlying object in different database.